# Difference between two sccm reports

Tags: sccm

I can't seem to get my mind wrapped around these two reports:

1. List of assets by compliance state for a configuration baseline
2. List of assets by compliance state for a configuration item in a configuration baseline

Can someone please enlighten me and possibly give some examples?

I'm trying to find out which assets are compliant with our Screen Saver Timeout.  We have a gpo (user config) that sets the timeout at 900secs.  I then created a CI that has a script to query the value of a registry key under HKCU.  I then created a CB and added the CI.  But I'm getting different compliance/noncompliance count when I run the two reports.  The first report says that I have 1700 compliant but when I run the second report, I only have 7 compliant.

Please please help!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A baseline can have multiple configuration items in it, so the first report would show you the overall compliance for all of the CIs in that baseline. The second report is for a single CI.

Difficult to say what may be causing the difference that you're seeing, but it's likely to do with either having multiple CIs in the baseline, or the first report may be showing Compliant for machines that haven't run the CI yet, whereas the second may only be reporting those that have actually run it?

Answer (score 0):

List of assets by compliance state for a configuration baseline

Lists the devices or users in a specified compliance state following the evaluation of a specified configuration baseline.

List of assets by compliance state for a configuration item in a configuration baseline

Lists the devices or users in a specified compliance state following the evaluation of a specified configuration item.

You can use Report Builder to review the query. If you are interested, you can find more information from database.

Here is relevant snippet of the difference between the two reports:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxgSX.png)

Based on the following query, we can find the meaning of the CIType.

select * from v_ConfigurationItems
 where CIType_ID in (2,50)

2= Baseline

50=Configuration Policy